# How to transfer specific columns of a table in one database into another database?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, data-import, database-table, data-export

I am using `pgAdmin 4` for `PostgreSQL`. I have two databases `A` and `B` each having a table called `records`. In database `A`, table `records` has 3 columns `person_id`, `shop_freq` and `time`, and has about 1000 rows. While in database `B`, table `records` has 4 columns `person_id`, `shop_freq`, `start_time` and `end_time`, and  is empty.

I want to transfer the data of columns `person_id` and `shop_freq` from database `A` to their corresponding columns in database `B`, and then transfer column `time` of database `A` to column `start_time`, and pass random data (for instance about 1 to 2 months after the `start time`) to the column `end_time`.

How can I do such a thing in an easy and clean way in `pgAdmin` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) statement to export the data to a file on the database server and use `COPY` with column names to load them into the other database.

To fill the missing column, run an `UPDATE` statement after the import.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. COPY TO works fine. But when I use COPY FROM I get the error: "Null value in column “name” violates not-null constraint"

Comment: Either create a "staging table" without that constraint, import the data there, update the column and then transfer it with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, or create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the target table that sets the column if it is NULL.